# How to detect if Software Keyboard is Visible on Android tv (fire tv)?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-tv, amazon-fire-tv

I know how to detect in android mobile devices when keyboard is shown, but how can I do that on android tv, or fire tv?

Comment: I guess I should make a calendar event and celebrate the anniversary of this question

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
fun isKeyBoardVisible() = ViewCompat.getRootWindowInsets(requireView())?.isVisible(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime()) ?: true
```